# spring boot cache busting angular partial

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, spring-boot, cache-control

In my spring MVC + angular  application .  I have configured cache busting using 
spring boot properties as below

```
spring.resources.cache-period=31536000  
spring.resources.chain.cache=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

This works perfectly for css/image/ js files.

index.html also served with

Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

My angular app is bootstrapped in index.html. 
when the angular app loads partials (html), they are loaded with aggressive caching(Cache-Control:max-age=31536000).  so any changes in partials are not  reflecting.  How can I disable cache for partials or limit the cache period for partials.

I have below structure

```
classes 
--Public 
 --org.xyz.com
      -controller
          -ControllerOne.js
      -service
           -Service.js
      -partial-one.html
      -partial-two.html
--Static
  --CSS
  --JS
  --img
--template
  - index.html
```